# How to create a line with "radial" shading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

How would you draw a black line with TikZ that shades to white/transparent radially ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1LYS.png)) between two coordinates?

Shading is possible for rectangles ([TikZ documentation, Ch. 46](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)), though I can not define the start and end coordinate as easily as with a line.

[image: line shading radially]

**Update:** Another approach was to create such an shaded rectangle was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164714/4640).

Comment: You might benefit from the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91689/visualize-data-on-a-variable-radius-graph-network/93858#93858 .

Comment: This approach looks rather complicated for a seemingly easy task. Let's see what the community comes up with.

Comment: Do you have only straight lines or it can have corners/curves in it? This is also a seemingly easy detail but a line is a pdf object with zero width no matter what kind of path is drawn over it. So it's not that straightforward. You might consider decorations for this.

Comment: @percusse I want to draw lines for now but an extension for arcs would be nice (though is not absolutely necessary). Before asking I had a look at the decorations-documentation but could not find a suitable approach.

Comment: How "fine" should the shading be? Would e.g. 5 steps be enough?

Comment: May be with [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80171/faded-or-blurred-lines/80207#80207)...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking of, but I couldn't manage to automate it. Actually, I think that this could be considered a duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, the answer linked by you goes in the right direction though, a couple of more steps would be nice to make it look smoother. The question is, if this can be automated or needs to be hardcoded.

Comment: @PeterPablo In my answer, there are 10 steps and the width of a step is `.2pt`. You can use `20` and `.1pt` instead... and choose a better value for `draw opacity`.

Comment: I posted my current solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164714/4640).