# How to draw microscope illumination light rays in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How would one go about drawing light / laser illumination rays using tikz? I would like to draw the schematic of an optical microscope illumination path. Examples of kinds of rays I would like to produce are:

- A linear gradient from out to in:

[image: olympus example]

- A cone shaped beam with a radial gradient:

[image: olympus example 2]

- The kind of laser illumination I am after is as follows:

[image: olympus laser]

Note: I am mainly interested in just the 'rays' in each picture. Not the optical elements or rest of the microscope setup. But they were the only pictures I could find that illustrate the look I am trying to achieve. I want to append them to my highly technical (lol) schematic so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-0.8,-0.2) -- (0.8,-0.2) -- (1.2,-0.6) -- (1.2,-1.8) -- (-1.2,-1.8) -- (-1.2,-0.6)--(-0.8,-0.2);
\draw  (-1.8,0.8) rectangle (1.8,0.4);
\draw (-1.2,1.4) -- (-1.6,2) -- (-1.8,3) -- (-1.8,3.8) -- (1.8,3.8) -- (1.8,3) -- (1.6,2) -- (1.2,1.4)--(-1.2,1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: template]

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the responses I have gotten 90% of what I am after:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\tikzset{lasernode/.style={
    left color=red,
    right color=red,
    middle color = white
    }
}
\tikzset{lasernode2/.style={
    left color=white,
    right color=white,
    middle color = red
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[lasernode] (-3.8,9.4) rectangle (-3.2,6.4);
\draw[lasernode] (-6.8,9) -- (-6.8,7.8) -- (-6.2,6.8) -- (-5.6,7.8) -- (-5.6,9) -- (-6.8,9);
\draw[lasernode2] (-5.4,9) -- (-5.4,7.8) -- (-4.8,6.8) -- (-4.2,7.8) -- (-4.2,9) -- (-5.4,9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: laser example]

What I want is for the shaded beam to stay perpendicular to the direction of propagation. Example of what I am after made with Photoshop is, but obviously with tikz correctly shading...:

[image: laser]

Thanks all

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to suggestions I am getting very close:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade right, left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!10, middle color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=fade rect, left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!70, middle color=transparent!100]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill opacity=0.9,thick, line cap=round,line join=round]
    \fill[red,path fading=fade right, fading angle=-30] (-0.2,1.8) -- (-1.6,3.4) -- (1.2,3.4) -- cycle;
    \fill[red,path fading=fade right, fading angle=210] (-0.2,1.8) -- (-1.6,3.4) -- (1.2,3.4) -- cycle;
    \draw (-1.6,3.4) -- (-0.2,1.8) -- (1.2,3.4);

    \fill [red,path fading=fade rect] (-0.2,3.4) rectangle (1.2,6.4);
    \fill [red,path fading=fade rect, fading angle=180]  (-1.6,3.4) rectangle (-0.2,6.4);
    \draw (-1.6,3.4) -- (-1.6,6.4);
    \draw (1.2,3.4) -- (1.2,6.4);

%    \fill  [blue,path fading=south](-0.8,7.8) rectangle (0.4,-3.4);    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am very happy with it but as you can see my implementation is quite messy. Basically after drawing a triangle I play around with rotations until it matches how I want, and then I draw another triangle behind it with the same rotation mirror vertically. The final problem is matching the horizontal beam up with the rotated one. Right now I am just doing trial and error. Thanks for all getting me onto the right track. If there is a solution to joining them together then I will be satisfied 100%.

Comment: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559)

Comment: @cmhughes Hi, what I am actually after is the .tikz code to produce rays similar to those depicted. I do not want to draw on any pictures. Thanks

Comment: Try `tikzedt` from www.tikzedt.org

Comment: [Faded or blurred lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80171/faded-or-blurred-lines), [TikZ: radial shading of a ring](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82425/1952)

Comment: I think you should start with this one: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/focused-ion-beam-system/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, the two topics @Ignasi suggested pretty much are exactly what I am after. I will post my solution once I am done playing around with them.

Comment: Potentially related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91689/visualize-data-on-a-variable-radius-graph-network/93858#93858 , http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172905/how-can-i-draw-a-curved-gradient-fade-in-tikz/173310#173310

Comment: Hi, Thanks @ChristianFeuersänger I had a go at them but they just seemed way too complicated to me. I am sure it would work but I have tried a new route which seems to work okay.

Comment: Why don't you try using the style defined in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80207/484) to draw the outline of the light rays (rather than the rays themselves), and then using the same outline path to clip?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a solution which "fakes" the shading by the method of repeatdly drawing the same shape, thinner and thinner and with a color more and more white:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]

\coordinate (top left) at (-1,5);
\coordinate (top right) at (1,5);
\coordinate (tip)   at (0,0);
\coordinate (bottom left) at (-1,1.5);
\coordinate (bottom right) at (1,1.5);

\colorlet{beamcolor}{red!80!orange!70}

\foreach \i in {0,0.01,...,1} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{sqrt(sqrt(\i))*100}
  \fill[white!\shade!beamcolor] 
        ($(top left)!\i!(top left-|tip)$)
     -- ($(bottom left)!\i!(bottom left-|tip)$) 
     -- (tip)
     -- ($(bottom right)!\i!(bottom right-|tip)$)
     -- ($(top right)!\i!(top right-|tip)$)
     -- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The loop iterates 100 times, from 0 to 1 at steps of 0.01. The shape is drawn "full width" in the first iteration, with color `beamcolor`, and each iteration of the loop draws it a little thinner (in a factor of 0.01 each time) and with a color which tends to white slowly.

The result is:

[image: Result]

Of course the method is cpu-intensive. If you increase the step from 0.01 to 0.1 for example, then the loop is repeated only ten times, which is faster, but produces a poor result (unless your beam is very thin and the "low resolution" cannot be seen).

## Update

Using the same idea, but instead of computing the shape for each iteration, this time we draw the same shape, only x-scaled thinner and thinner (this time I used 0.03 as step)

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\colorlet{beamcolor}{red!80!orange!70}

\foreach \i in {1, 0.97, ..., 0} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{\i*\i*100}
  \fill[beamcolor!\shade!white, x=\i cm] 
        (-1,5) -- (-1,1.5) -- (0,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,5) -- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result2]

## Update 2. Explanations and more examples

As requested by the OP in a comment, here is a detailed explanation of the code for the last solution.

- `\colorlet` serves obviously to define a new color name, allowing to specify the color as a `xcolor` *mixing*, which uses the syntax `color1!%!color2`, being `%` the desired percentage of `color1`. The resulting color can be mixed again by appending another `!%`, etc. If `color2` is omitted, it is assumed to be `white`. So, in our code, `beamcolor`  will be a mix of red and orange (80% red and thus 20% orange), and then this color is mixed again with white (70% of the color and thus 30% of white).
- `\foreach \i in {1, 0.97, ..., 0}` declares a loop which uses `\i` as loop variable. This variable will start with value 1, then, at the next iteration it will be 0.97, and next iterations decrease `\i` in steps of 0.03. The step is automatically derived from the two first values specified in the braces. When `\i` reaches 0, the loop ends. In the following code `\i` is the horizontal scale of the beam, and the amount of `beamcolor` used to fill.
- `\pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{\i*\i*100}` computes the expression `\i*\i*100` and stores the result in the macro named `\shade`. So, for the first iteration of the loop `\shade` will be equal to 100, in the next iteration it will be 0.97*0.97*100 which is 94.09 etc. This value is the % of `beamcolor` present in the shape we will draw later. So, in the first iteration the shape will be filled with a color 100% `beamcolor`. The next iteration it will be 94.09% `beamcolor` (and thus 5.91% white), etc.. In the last iteration it will be 0% `beamcolor` and thus 100% white.
- `\fill[beamcolor!\shade!white, x=\i cm]` This will draw a geometric shape and fill it in a solid color (not a gradient!). The color will be a mixing between `beamcolor` and `white`, being `\shade` the amount (in %) of `beamcolor`. See previous paragraph. The option `x=\i cm` assigns the value `\i cm` to vector `x`, which determines the horizontal scale of the drawing. So, in the first iteration `x=1cm`, in the next one 'x=0.97cm` etc. This causes the shape drawn to be thinner in each iteration.
- `(-1,5) -- (-1,1.5) -- (0,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,5) -- cycle;` This is the shape to be drawn. The values of the coordinates do not specify any unit, and thus tikz uses `x` as unit for the x-coordinate and `y` (1cm by default) as unit for the y-coordinate. As seen in previous paragraph, the value of `x` is different for each iteration of the loop.

The key to understand why this code produces the desired result is to realize that the shape being drawn has horizontal symmetry along y-axis. So, reducing `x` scale the new figure is still symmetric through the same axis.

The following figure in which the loop is repeated only 3 times, and we use very different colors for each filling, could make the process more clear:

```
\foreach \i/\color in {1/green, 0.75/red, 0.25/blue} {
  \fill[\color, x=\i cm] 
        (-1,5) -- (-1,1.5) -- (0,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,5) -- cycle;
}
```

[image: simplified example]

Now, some caveats.

The above code works under assumption than the shape is symmetric around y-axis. If you, for example, add 1 to all x-coordinates, this is not longer true, and thus the result is not what it is desired. However, this can be avoided by using `xshift` option instead of manipulating the coordinates of the shade. Also, the option `rotate` can be used to rotate the beam around its tip. If both `xshift` and `rotate` are to be used, the shifting should happen first.

For example:

```
\colorlet{beamcolor}{red!80!orange!70}

\foreach \i in {1, 0.97, ..., 0} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{\i*\i*100}
  \fill[beamcolor!\shade!white, x=\i cm, rotate=70] 
        (-1,5) -- (-1,1.5) -- (0,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,5) -- cycle;
}

\colorlet{beamcolor}{green!80!orange!70}

\foreach \i in {1, 0.97, ..., 0} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{\i*\i*100}
  \fill[beamcolor!\shade!white, x=\i cm,  xshift=1cm, rotate=-20] 
        (-1,5) -- (-1,1.5) -- (0,0) -- (1,1.5) -- (1,5) -- cycle;
}

\draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
```

Produces:

[image: Result]

Note also that this solution can be easily extended to other beam-like shapes:

```
\foreach \i in {1, 0.97, ..., 0} {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\shade}{\i*\i*100}
  \fill[beamcolor!\shade!white, x=\i cm] 
        (-1,5) -- (-1,2.5) -- (-0.8, 1.5) -- (0,0) -- (0.8, 1.5) -- (1,2.5) -- (1,5) -- cycle;
}
```

[image: Another shape]

Comment: These diagrams are so good I want to cry. Thanks!

Comment: Just for my own learning, could you please explain what each line of code does in the second solution? I cant understand how it knows to shade light then dark again. Thanks. Tikz is incredible.

Comment: @SteveHatcher See updated answer

Comment: mate that's unreal, thanks for going to so much effort. I hope many users see and benefit from this. The level of professionalism achievable by a Tikz'er in the know is phenomenal. By the way I was not holding my bounty for 'ransom' when asking for the additional descriptions. I thought that when I accept the answer the bounty is transferred automatically - not that I had to click it. Once I can award it (5 hours) I will. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveHatcher  Don't worry about the bounty. I didn't provided the explanations for getting it, but in the hope of being useful to others, and to contribute to increase the tikz-savviness of the universe :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can implement @JLDiaz's clever "fake gradient" idea easily in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) as well.

- Variables of type `color` are just 3d vectors, and we can interpolate
  from `a` to `b` using the square bracket syntax: `p[a,b]` returns a
  vector that is `p` of the way from `a` to `b`.
- If we make the beams symmetrical about the x-axis we can use `yscaled`
  to control the width of the strip we are filling each time.  Then we can 
  capture them as `picture` variables with `image()` and move them about as needed.

Even with 1000 iterations it seems pretty speedy on my machine, but I
   can't see much difference on screen with more than 20 iterations.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

n := 20; % seems ok up to 1000s on my machine but hard to see difference above 20 on screen
r := 1.2; % controls gradient

path beam_outline, limb; 
limb = origin -- (20,10) --  (40,15)  -- (100, 20) -- (300, 20);
beam_outline = limb -- reverse (limb reflectedabout(left,right)) & cycle;

picture beam, another_beam;
beam = image( for i=n step -1 until 0:
  fill beam_outline yscaled (i/n) withcolor ((i/n)**r)[background,blue];
endfor);
another_beam = image( for i=n step -1 until 0:
  fill beam_outline yscaled (i/n) withcolor ((i/n)**r)[red, background];
endfor);

draw beam rotated 30;
draw another_beam rotated 150 shifted 10 left;

endfig;
end.
```

On the left we are shading from background to color, and on the right the other way round.
Note that all I did was to swap the order of the color and the background in the brackets.

[image: Red and blue beams]

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This way of drawing them really is great!